# How to make model IDs in Rails unpredictable and random

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a rails app that, by its nature, CANNOT require users to register, and thus cannot use authentication as the usual means to protect records. (I know, I know...)   User information here is limited to email addresses. So I do need a way to make my model IDs unpredictable so that other IDs cannot be easily guessed. (I know, I know...)

I have tried using plugins like uuidtools to randomize ids as records are created, like so:

```
require 'uuidtools'
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
 def before_create() 
  self.id = OpenSSL::Digest.SHA1.hexdigest(UUID.timestamp_create()) 
 end 
end
```

...This looks good at first, but funny things happen. ActiveRecord sometimes tries to insert a 0 value into the id and I get errors such as 'can't find Post with id=0' etc...

I've run out of ideas. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid this gem for your need

Answer (score 22):

In your model,  do this:

```
before_create :randomize_id

...

private
def randomize_id
  begin
    self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000)
  end while Model.where(id: self.id).exists?
end
```

Comment: With this method, is it possible for multiple posts to have the same random_number??

Comment: @Justin No it is not, because the while loop checks if an object with that id already exists (you have to replace *Model* with Post in your case)

Comment: as long as you have less than a million users :P

Comment: Instead of model, you can say `self.class` and put it into a base ActiveRecord model that your models extend from. Also increase the random number to maximum allowed by the database.

Comment: This isn't thread safe-- I've seen a solution like this create duplicate entries in a production system.

Answer (score 17):

Best way is to use `SecureRandom.uuid` that generates a V4 UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier).

It is virtually completely random and unique (collision probability is something like one over tens of trillions) : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

This should do the job :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create :generate_random_id

 private 
 def generate_random_id
   self.id = SecureRandom.uuid
 end 
end
```

Or if you are using Rails >= 4 and PostgreSQL, you can have it generating them for you :

```
create_table :posts, id: :uuid do |t|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Do I need to change the ID from integer to String? Does not seems to work unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

The thing that is going wrong here is that self.id requires an int and OpenSSL::Digest.SHA1.hexdigest(UUID.timestamp_create()) returns a string with non-numeric characters which would lead to the value '0' being actually stored in the database

Comment: Not necessarily, you can define your database to have a string for the ID column.  It may not be ideal, but it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to generate a token or checksum or whatever in a second column during record creation, and in all cases your controllers query for an object, use `Model.find_by_id_and_token`.

You'll then always generate URLs that contain and require both the id and token.

Comment: The other reason to do it this way (adding a token/checksum) is that ActiveRecord is simply easier when the primary keys are integers -- as far as associations are concerned.