# Problem with a gem: "no such file to load" 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I used 'uuidtools' gem in my controller this way:

```
  def create
    require 'uuidtools'
    game = Game.new
    game.permalink = Base64.encode64(UUIDTools::UUID.random_create)[0..8]
    game.save 
    redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'index'
  end
```

I get this error about the requiring of 'uuidtools':

```
no such file to load -- uuidtools
```

(I added the gem to my gem file.)

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Oded

Comment: I have just installed uuidtools and tested it in my rails console.  Can you do UUIDTools::UUID.random_create in your rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

What I did is to migrate the use of 'uuidtools' from the controller to the model:

```
  class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :create_permalink

  def create_permalink
    self.permalink = Base64.encode64(UUIDTools::UUID.random_create)[0..8]
  end  

  end
```

Comment: emmm no. and the moving method to the model is better than leaving it in the controller (basic stuff you should know...)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps restarting the server would also had fixed the problem

Comment: Restarting webrick after the `bundle install` fixes it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run 'bundle install' to install the gem ?

Comment: are you sure that you need to require 'uuidtools' ? Does it work if you remove this line ?

Comment: I think yes because if I dont require I get this error: "uninitialized constant GamesController::UUIDTools"

Comment: What I did is based on an answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165784/use-a-random-string-as-id-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: try to use "include GamesController::UUIDTools" instead.

Comment: or just 'include GamesController'

Comment: When I add: "include GamesController::UUIDTools" it gives me:  uninitialized constant GamesController::UUIDTools
And when I add "'include GamesController" it gives me:
undefined method `include' for #<GamesController:0x5bb6b28>